# Performing Segue programmatically from superclass buttons

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uistoryboard, superclass

All, 
My app requires me to use custom buttons on different view controllers/screens. Since I didn't want to go through the effort of creating them multiple times on the storyboard and then making any required modifications multiple times, I created a superclass that has the buttons in viewdidload and then I inherit this class in my different view controllers. Now, I want to perform segues from these buttons. The way I want it to work is that each button will segue to the same controller/view regardless of the view from where its tapped on. Now, I know that as far as segues programmatically are concerned, I have two options, the performseguewithidentifier and pushviewController. I'm not completely sure how either one would work in my case? At the moment, I'm trying to use performseguewithidentifier by creating a segue from the superclass controller in storyboard but then things compile and then when i tap on the button my app crashes giving me an unrecognized selector sent to instance exception. I can't really use the pushviewController option since this superclass controller is itself not part of my navigation controller. 
Any idea how I can do my button segues so that they are inherited to other controllers?

A few other details in order to completely clarify the situation: My superclass does have a corresponding view controller on the storyboard, but this is not part of my navigation controller stack and hence is not connected to anything else. The reason I've done it this way is because my superclass is just for inheriting the buttons, it doesn't have any other purpose really. All the other view controllers that subclass it are in storyboard and are a part of the navigation stack. The reason I went this route for my buttons is because I have them as part of every screen in my app and I didn't want to create them multiple times in storyboard because then any changes that I wanted to make would have to be made across all controllers. With a superclass controller, I would just need to change things once. I wasn't sure about how to subclass UIButton and then work with segues. Is that an option I should consider?

Comment: In your segue version, what type of segue do you envision? Push or modal or ...?

Comment: As per push view controller, push segue makes no sense outside of a navigation controller context, as it is your nav controller that maintains the stack of view controllers to push on and pop off

Comment: Does presenting one viewController from another modally make sense in your case?

Comment: Hmm, I would rather not present modally since I need the nav bar and also that would mean that my superclass VC would be responsible for dismissing the modal view which would make everything very messy. Can you think of something that I could implement through storyboards that might help me?

Comment: I just always assumed that there might be a set method to deal with superclasses and such in objective C. I guess not.

Comment: It might help to describe more exactly your setup. EG - does your "superclass" (a viewController) have a corresponding xib or storyboard item? Or do its subclasssed viewControllers? Or is this all in code? if in code, where does the storyboard come into play? What are the custom features of buttons that you want to create? Could you rather create custom button subclass? Perhaps you could expand / restructure your question with some more of this kind of detail.

Comment: @HeWas I added answers to your questions in my original post. Do things make more sense now?